# validating a date in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is the client script function for an asp.net validation control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateDateControl(sender, args) {

        var d = new Date(args.Value);

        args.IsValid = (Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === "[object Date]");

        if (!args.IsValid) {
            sender.innerText = "Client: Invalid date";
        }     

        return args.IsValid;
    }
</script>

Immediate Window Results:
d
NaN
Object.prototype.toString.call(d) === "[object Date]"
true
```

Why is the comparison evaluating True?

Comment: I cannot understad your question. Please, post more details. Sorry :)

Comment: An invalid date is still a date object, it just can't be represented properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `new Date('as;dlas;ld,as;dl,as')` is still a `Date` object.

```
> var d = new Date('as;dlas;ld,as;dl,as')
  undefined
> d.toString()
  "Invalid Date"
> Object.prototype.toString.call(d)
  "[object Date]"
```

A better way to check date validity is to see that `Date.getTime()` does not return `NaN`:

```
function validateDateControl(sender, args) {

    var d = new Date(args.Value);

    args.IsValid = !isNaN(d.getTime());

    if (!args.IsValid) {
        sender.innerText = "Client: Invalid date";
    }     

    return args.IsValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's an object of type Date but the value (what is shown in string representation of the object itself, not the type) is invalid.